# Can UNION ALL be performed asynchronously on linked servers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asynchronous

I have the following query that is run on > 30 remote linked servers (please don't ask me why it isn't warehoused, that's a completely different issue).

```
SELECT * FROM table WITH (NOLOCK)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM server1.table WITH (NOLOCK)
UNION ALL
...
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to make this run asynchronously? Running this can take quite some time depending on latencies and I'd like to optimise so that I'm not stuck waiting for a couple slow connections.

All of the tables are of identical schema and the order in which they are unioned really doesn't matter.

Comment: you could run them all on separate connection, dumping into a table, then select from the table. What do you want to show anyway if you don't have all the data yet?

Comment: Whether or not this will happen in parallel and how is up to the optimizer (it will happen "asynchronously" in any case, in that SQL Server does not use busy waiting for operations). You can't really enforce this, other than by using undocumented tricks like trace flag 8649, and even then it's not a given that this will cause parallel remote access. If you want to ensure this happens with as much parallelism as possible you'd have to use client code.